# default value for cascading dropdown is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, .net-2.0

Suppose parent dropdown is car (Values are car1, car2, car3)and its child is color(for car1 R Y G B, For car2 R Yand for car3 G B).

Now on selection of car2 R and Y will appear and select R, then again made the change on car and select car3 then again select is comiing with G and B and select B.

Now if I select again in car, car1 then the child is populating with the values of car1 but it takes the B as a default value as it was previously selected and also present for car1 too.

This case is only happen. on select of child value which is availble for both parent selection

Answer (score 0):

On the selection of car you can fixed the dropdown selected value

```
Dropdown.selectedindex =0;
```

so that it will populate with 1st value which is "select". 
 Hope this will help.